# Number of pairs of users who are onsite at the same time. Solve in O(nlogn)

Tags: python, algorithm, sorting, merge, time-complexity

I'm trying the problem which is given as:

New friends. Each of n users spends some time on a social media site. For each i = 1, ..., n, user i enters the site at a time ai and leaves at time bi ≥ ai. You are interested in the question: 
how many distinct pairs of users are on the site at the same time? (Here, the pair (i, j) is the same as the pair (j, i)).
Example: Suppose there are 5 users with the following entering and leaving times: 
User EnterTime LeaveTime

| User | Enter Time | Leave Time |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 4 |
| 2 | 2 | 5 |
| 3 | 7 | 9 |
| 4 | 9 | 10 |
| 5 | 6 | 10 |

Then, the number of distinct pairs of users who are on the site at the same time is four: these pairs are (1, 2), (3, 4), (4, 5), (3, 5). Note: If the Leave Time of one user is the same as the Enter Time of another, this counts as an overlap. For example, user 3’s Leave Time is 9, and User 4’s Enter Time is 9, and this counts as an overlap.

I am having trouble in part b which is:
Given input (a1, b1), (a2, b2), ..., (an, bn) as above. Give an O(n log(n))-time algorithm to do the same task and analyze its running time. (Hint: consider sorting relevant events by time).
Tried the following code but the answer doesn't seem to be right.

```
count = 0
def merge(left, right):
    global count
    result = []
    i = 0
    j = 0
    while i < len(left) and j < len(right):
        if left[i][0] == right[j][0] or left[i][1] == right[j][1]:
                count += 1
        if left[i][1] < right[j][1]:
            if right[j][0] <= left[i][1]:
                count += 1
            result.append(left[i])
            i += 1
        else:
            result.append(right[j])
            j += 1
    while i < len(left):#the only left element should be compared with the rest of the elements
        result.append(left[i])
        i += 1
    while j < len(right):
        result.append(right[j])
        j += 1
    return result

def mergeSort(lst):
    if len(lst) < 2:
        return lst
    else:
        mid = len(lst) // 2
        left = mergeSort(lst[:mid])
        right = mergeSort(lst[mid:])
        return merge(left, right)
lst = [(1, 4), (2, 5), (7, 9), (9, 10), (6, 10)]
print(mergeSort(lst))
print("Number of pairs online: ", count)
# gives 3, should be 4
```

Please guide me if possible. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hello Nabeel! Look for details to interval intersection problems, it will help you understand the principles and come up with a solution by yourself.

Comment: Thanks a lot for showing me the path. I have been searching ever since you commented. But I still don't understand how I would be able to do this in O(nlogn) time. I really need to solve this as the deadline is near.

Answer (score 2):

I guess they had something like this in mind.

```
lst = [(1, 4), (2, 5), (7, 9), (9, 10), (6, 10)]
events = []
for enter, leave in lst:
    events.append((enter, "enter"))
    events.append((leave, "leave"))
# At the same time, enter is before leave, which is what we want.
events.sort()
pairs = 0
onsite = 0
for _time, kind in events:
    if kind == "enter":
        pairs += onsite
        onsite += 1
    elif kind == "leave":
        onsite -= 1
    else:
        assert False
print(pairs)
```